# SQLAlchemy 2.0 migration - Connection to Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am just testing out the SQLAlchemy 1.4 library out and I noticed in the foreseeable future they changing certain core functionalities.  I generally connect to a database shown below, moving forward they mentioned they are going to remove this `bind` method on the `MetaBase` class, what is going to be the set standard of writing this?

```
def output_log(msg):
    connector = create_engine("mylogin")
    metadata = MetaData(bind=connector)
    log = Table("mytable", metadata, autoload=True)
    sess = connector.connect()
    i = insert(log).values({"Message": msg})
    sess.execute(i)
    sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes and background for this are described in [“Implicit” and “Connectionless” execution, “bound metadata” removed](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-20-implicit-execution).

You can rewrite your code as follows:

```py
def output_log(msg):
    engine = create_engine("mylogin")
    metadata = MetaData()
    log = Table("mytable", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    sess = engine.connect()
    i = log.insert().values({"Message": msg})
    sess.execute(i)
    sess.commit()
    sess.close()
```

Or for completeness using `with`:

```py
    with engine.begin() as sess:
        i = log.insert().values({"Message": msg})
        sess.execute(i)
```

And the other `half` option with the future `commit`:

```py
    with engine.connect() as sess:
        i = log.insert().values({"Message": msg})
        sess.execute(i)
        sess.commit()
```

Comment: I thought it was advising against this way? It says this in the "many choices" box:
```# execute from connection, but it autocommits?
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: No, they are not advising against this way. They have removed all the various ways to `#OneChoice` for connecting. See the box underneath the `many choices'. They only difference is that they are using `with` which calls `__exit__()` before return (which calls `close()`).

Comment: @dko512 the example you are talking about is missing the required `commit` when using `connect` in SQLAlchemy>1.4.

Comment: Oh I see, so in the future version (>1.4) they recommend using the `with` statement but it would be still viable to manually `close()` as shown in your adjustment of my initial function?

Comment: Using the context manger is only a helpful extension but using the function with the function calls is still valid! The advantage of using the context manger is that you don’t have to think about closing the connection (or committing if using `begin()`.